# Troubleshooting Delayed Service Startup in systemd: Historical Resource Prioritization?

Tags: systemd

I'm investigating the delay in the startup of my service `my-service.service` even though it's configured to start after `network.target`. Upon using `systemd-analyze plot`, I noticed that `my-service.service` starts 30 seconds after `network.target`, which seems unusually delayed.

To troubleshoot, I conducted an experiment where I created a simple unit file named `foo.service`, which started only 100 ms after `network.target`. Curiously, when I copied the configuration from `foo.service` to `my-service.service` and restarted my Raspberry Pi, `my-service.service` still exhibited the 30-second delay, despite having the same configuration as `foo.service`.

I'm puzzled as to why `my-service.service` experiences this delay compared to `foo.service`, even though their configurations are identical. I'm curious if there's any historical intelligence built into systemd, wherein `my-service.service` might have historically required more resources, leading it to start later even after configuration changes.

Could someone shed light on why `my-service.service` persists in starting 30 seconds after `network.target`, despite sharing the same configuration as `foo.service`?

- `foo.service`

  ```ini
  [Unit]
  Description=foo.service
  After=network.target

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/home/pi/foo.sh

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- `foo.sh`

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  while sleep 1; do echo "executing foo.sh"; done
  ```

Comment: Is the `[Unit]` section header missing only from your post or also from the actual files?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Sorry, that was a bad copy+paste. I've added [Unit] section header